# Are tutorial type articles their own distinct category? (in physics)

Tags: journals, physics

In 2021, PRX Quantum released a new type of publication distinct from articles and reviews known as the tutorial. This is described as:

> PRX Quantum began publishing Tutorials to help the quantum community educate the next generation of quantum scientists. Rather than provide a comprehensive overview of the field, as is typically found in a Review paper, Tutorials are hands-on guides written by experts invited by the editorial leadership of the journal. Tutorials focus on the essential knowledge and relevant references that will allow newcomers to a research field, approach, or methodology efficiently move forward with their work. For example, they should ideally help researchers migrate to a new field, bridge knowledge gaps for interdisciplinary collaborators, and contribute to the education and development of PhD students and postdocs. They focus on explaining well-established milestone concepts, the latest techniques, and developments in the field, providing a flavor of current research.

I've noticed these hand hold the reader very closely and are in its own distinct category from review articles as mentioned in the quote. Where can I find a repository of other such journals and what exactly am I looking for in terms of search words when it comes to this looking for journals that will publish this type of article? Also, do the somewhat more vanilla journals such as "PRB" or "EJP" accept these kinds of tutorial articles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It feels to me like this recent PRX Quantum approach is fairly novel, and I'm fairly jealous that I haven't seen anything like that in areas that I'm responsible for teaching.

If I were looking for resources like this, there are a number of approaches I would try.  Since the publication class you're describing looks like just another type of publication in a journal, I would try to search for people who have cited publications of this type, and hope to hit some article on education that compares the efficacy of works of this type to more traditional methods.  If such papers exist, they may well point you to other similar resources.

A second approach would be to try to find journals that specialize in education in the areas you're interested in.  This, of course, would cast a wider net than what you're looking for, but the advantage is that you may find a bigger picture that brings you even more tools.  As an example of such a journal, I'll point you to [Advances in Physiology Education](https://journals.physiology.org/journal/advances)

Lastly, a chat with a good university librarian when you're looking for resources is never a bad idea.

Good Luck!  If you do find such resources, it would be fantastic if you can post them as an answer to your own question!

Answer (score 1):

One way journals compete is by offering different content types and filling different niches. Tutorials is a fairly unique type that, as far as I know, is only offered by two APS journals: PRX Quantum and PRX Energy. Traditionally in physics, guides and hands-on material have commonly been written up as lecture notes. Especially summer school lecture notes can have a similar nature. A fairly recent avenue that may be of interest is the journal SciPost Physics Lecture Notes. Otherwise, lecture notes have often ended up being published in various forms, including book volumes, review articles, or just PDFs. Finally, as Scott Seidman writes, some pedagogical material is published by the more education-focused American Journal of Physics.